# How to show two rows of div in single div

Tags: php, html, css

I am showing div in one row using for loop.  first div show done but insert new div. 
 How to insert new div with same as first div. Thanks in advanced.
Now this showing as -

```
"first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div "
```

Now I want to show another div below of first div using same for loop.

I want like this-

```
"first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div first-div"

"minor-div minor-div minor-div minor-div minor-div minor-div minor-div minor-div"
```

CSS CODE-

```
#default-Div{
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 830px;
white-space:nowrap;
height: 110px;
```

}

```
.calender-column{
width:160px;
height:110px;    
border:1px solid #0174DF;
    display:inline-block;
```

PHP - HTML CODE -

```
<div id="default-Div"  >
<?php $temp=1; for($j=0;$j<30;$j++){?>

<div id="calender-column<?php echo $temp;?>" class="calender-column"   >

<?php $temp++; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: .calender-column means my first-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `display: inline;` with `width` and `height`, because that would no longer be inline. You can check the [CSS Specification on display](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) for more detailed information. Suffice to say, with `display: inline;`, this is not possible.

Thankfully, there's a new(ish) property value for `display` that will do exactly what you want: `display: inline-block;` -- to be inline in the document flow, but kinda-sorta display like a block-level element.

```
.calender-column{
width:160px;
height:110px;    
border:1px solid #0174DF;
    display:inline-block; }
```

... and you'll be fine :)

Note: the only caveat is, `inline-block` does not work in IE 6 or 7. You can, however, change the display to purely `inline` just for those two browsers, as they incorrectly render `inline` as `inline-block` anyway.